# How to form a BSpline function from a 3DS/OBJ import in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, bspline

Here is an example 3D geometry.

```
dat=Import["ExampleData/747.3ds.gz", ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Now if one wants to get a BSplineFunction for this 3D geometry what is the easiest way to do it?

I can see the parts in Mathematica using the following command.

```
parts = Length[(dat // First // Last)];
```

and here comes the 3D points after extraction.

```
ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[Map[((dat // First // Last)[[#]] /. 
  GraphicsComplex[a_, b_] -> List[a]) &, Range[parts]], 1]]
```

I hope there is a general method so that we can form a BSpline function from any 3D graphics complex.
I suppose the general method will be able to convert Mathematica 3D representations in continuous BSplines representation.

Now we will elaborate according to the example given by belisarius.

```
v={{0,0,0},{2,0,0},{2,2,0},{0,2,0},{1,1,2}};
i={{1,2,5},{2,3,5},{3,4,5},{4,1,5}};
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5],GraphicsComplex[v,Polygon[i]]}]
```

[image]

We can simply form the input for the BSpline surface for this example.

```
dat = Table[Map[v[[#]] &, i[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[i]}];
```

Now let's see the surface that comes out if we consider the underlying vertices.

```
Show[
     (* Vertices *)
     ListPointPlot3D[v,PlotStyle->{{Black,PointSize[.03]}}],
     (* The 3D solid *)
     Graphics3D[{Opacity[.4],GraphicsComplex[v,Polygon[i]]}],
     (* The BSpline surface *)
     Graphics3D[{Opacity[.9],FaceForm[Red,Yellow],
                 BSplineSurface[dat, SplineDegree-> {1,2},SplineClosed->{True,False}]}
                ],
     Boxed-> False,Axes-> None
    ]
```

[image]

Once this surface is formed I thought it will be possible to make a BSplineFunction in some way. But what I get is completely different from the above surface.

```
func = BSplineFunction[dat, SplineDegree -> {1, 2},SplineClosed -> {True, False}];
Plot3D[func[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None,PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

So am I making some conceptual mistake here?

Comment: Before I forget: PlatoManiac, welcome on StackOverflow! Don't forget to vote for answer(s) below that you like and, if one of them answers your question to your satisfaction, please accept it by using the check-mark next to the answer. You can change your choice whenever you like.

Comment: @Sjoerd Actually you are right! The answer is still not there. We still did not find how to form this type of BSpline for much more complex 3D imports like the Boing model.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question needs further clarification.

The .3DS are mainly Polygon sets like this one:

```
v = {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 2}};
i = {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 1, 5}};
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[i]]}]
```

[image]

So, it is not obvious how to get Spline surfaces to model this.

Perhaps you can elaborate a little with this example.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

Minor detail: Your spline is a bit warped and that's because of your choice of `SplineDegree`. For the pyramid case I'd choose {2,1} instead of {1,2}.
That will give you a cone instead of the soft-ice cone you now have. Of course, that's all rather arbitrary and beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

[image]

Now for your question why a 3D plot of the `BSplineFunction` doesn't give the same results as a `Graphics3D` of a `BSplineSurface` with the same control points. The problem is that you assume that the two parameters in the `BSplineFunction` correspond to x and y of a Cartesian coordinate system. Well, they don't. Those parameters are part of an internal parametric description of the surface, in which varying these two parameters yields a set of 3D points, so you have to use `ParametricPlot3D` here.

So, if you change your `Plot3D` into `ParametricPlot3D` you'll see all is fine.

I hope this answers you final question. Does this also answer your question how to convert a 3D polygon based model to a spline based model? One of the problems you face is that a spline doesn't usually  go through its control points, as a kind of interpolating function.

Comment: There are similar constructs with the interpolating property. I think the name of the beasts are Catmull-Rom or something like that

Comment: I am sorry!!! I made the mistake in hurry. I always use ParametricPlot3D for BSpline visualization. Not sleeping last night and editing the post this morning might be the reason. Thanks anyways!!

Comment: However I will now try applying the same trick with the Boeing 3DS model. The GraphicsComplex in that case seems to be more complex than the pyramid we were playing so far.